# Show $M \bigotimes\limits_R N$ is an $R-S-$bimodule via $s\sum\limits_\text{finite} m_i \otimes n_i = \sum\limits_\text{finite} m_i \otimes (sn_i)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

$M$ an $R$-module, $N$ an $R-S-$bimodule. Show $M \bigotimes\limits_R N$ is an $R-S-$bimodule via $s\sum\limits_\text{finite} m_i \otimes n_i = \sum\limits_\text{finite} m_i \otimes (sn_i)$.

How would I show this using the summations above?

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: All I know of $R$ is that it is a ring.

Comment: What's the point of $P$ ?

Comment: I think that P is important because of s in the equation.

Comment: $P$ doesn't have anything to do with the problem. Also, $N$ is a *right* $S$-module and $M\otimes_RN$ is also a *right* $S$ module.

Comment: Ok. I have remove the part with $P$.

Comment: You still have $S$ acting on the left.